# Using polar coordinates to find the area of the region inside circle outside the cardioid

Tags: area, polar-coordinates

Using polar coordinates to find the area of the region inside the circle $r = 1$ and outside the cardioid $r = 1 + \cos(\theta).$

Would the limits for $\theta$ be from -$\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ and the limits for $r$ be from $1+\cos(\theta)$ to $1$?

If not what should they be?

Comment: I'd say limits from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$ and then double the result. Here you can see an useful example http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArea.aspx

Comment: @Raffaele Should the integral be:
$$2\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \int_{1+cos\theta}^{1} r \,dr\,d\theta$$
or
$$2\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \int_{1}^{1+cos\theta} r \,dr\,d\theta$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area is
$$2\cdot \frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\pi } \left(1-(\cos \theta+1)^2\right) \, d\theta=2-\frac{\pi}{4}$$